# How to send a scheduled FCM message using the event_time parameter of the FCM Post API?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a **scheduled** push notification using firebase messaging from my flutter app.

I use the below code to send a push notification from my app, which works without any issues:

```
  Future<bool> callOnFcmApiSendPushNotifications(String title, String body, List<dynamic> receivers, {String? image = "", String screen = ''}) async {
print('normal message');
List<dynamic> tokens = await pushNotificationsManager.getTokens(receivers);

final postUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
Map<String, dynamic> data;
  data = {
    "registration_ids" : tokens,
    "collapse_key" : "type_a",
    "notification" : {
      "title": title,
      "body" : body,
      "sound": "default",
      "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",

    },
    'data':{
      "title": title,
      "body": body,
      "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      "screen": screen,
    },


  };



final headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': authKey

};

final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(postUrl),
    body: json.encode(data),
    encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    headers: headers);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return true;
} else {
  print(' FCM error');
  return false;
}
```

}

Now for some notifications, I want to send them at 11AM the next day, which I tried to implement using the `event_time` parameter of the API as per the code below. However, when I try this code, the notification arrives immediately at the receiver, without the required delay.

```
  Future<bool> callOnFcmApiSendDelayedPushNotifications(String title, String body, List<dynamic> receivers, {String? image = "", String screen = ''}) async {


List<dynamic> tokens = await pushNotificationsManager.getTokens(receivers);

// set time to 11AM next day
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
DateTime dtTomorrow = DateTime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day+1, 11);

final postUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
Map<String, dynamic> data;

  data = {
    "registration_ids" : tokens,
    "collapse_key" : "type_a",
    "notification" : {
      "title": title,
      "body" : body,
      "event_time": Timestamp.fromDate(dtTomorrow).millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
      "sound": "default",
      "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",

    },
    'data':{
      "title": title,
      "body": body,
      "event_time": Timestamp.fromDate(dtTomorrow).millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
      "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      "screen": screen,
    },


  };



final headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': authKey

};

final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(postUrl),
    body: json.encode(data),
    encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    headers: headers);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

}

I know it is possible to send scheduled push notifications from the Firebase console, but is there any way to send a scheduled notification from the app? Note that I am on a free spark plan so cloud functions cannot be used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That field is used for sorting notifications, not for delayed send. One option would be to schedule a task using a work manager to send the notification at the right time: https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

Comment: Thanks! Does the workmanager execute even if the user closes the app? Because the delay I am looking for is 12-24hours\

Comment: As Dan commented, there is no way to tell the FCM API to deliver the message at a certain time, but what you *can* do is deliver a *data only* message right away, and then hold displaying it in the recipient until a certain time.

Comment: Yes this is intended for background tasks and not just while the app is in the foreground.